# 3D display, that's actually3D

Tags: display, oled, 3d

So one night, (last night) i was in bed trying to get to sleep, and then something came to mind, this one thing came to my mind and got me excited.

You may now be wondering what came to my mind, or not, if you read the title. So, i came here to tell you about what came to my mind and hope one of you can answer it, and tell me why it wouldn't/would work. Sorry if that's more of a discussion, if you think that well i'd have to disagree, this is a question of my mind that i want someone to answer, it may seem like a discussion but i don't really think it is.

I started thinking about a cube,  Let's say, this cube:
[image: Simple 3D cube made in blender.]
With this simple cube i had an idea, and idea about 3D, actual 3D images.(?) Now, let's add some simple protectors on the sides, to get rid of the pointy parts and also make it not brake and/or crack when dropped. [image: The same cube in blender, but with protectors.]
Let's quickly pretend that those corners are smooth, can't be asked modeling right now as i want to write this down for you all to answer my question to come.

So with this cube we have, let's replace the normal cube with a organic LED (OLED,  organic light-emitting diode)

Now it should more look like this:
[image: The same cube but with a OLED as a base]
This is a solid cube of OLEDs, should cost a LOT to make this, but that's expected, this is meant to be small enough to balance it on your hand but yet be a little bit bigger than your hand. So, when powered and after lots of coding, you should be able to put a 3d model displayed inside of it, like this

[image: The cube displaying a sphere inside.]
Now, with also some wiring around the edges, i wonder, is this possible and can it be done? That is my question. Thanks for reading this far!

*few notes: sorry for poor quality images, it's in blender's cycles and i didn't put many samples on, and the poor quality models, i didn't have time for it. Also, the sphere inside of the glass wouldn't look like that in real life.*

Thank you!

EDIT: I came here to have my qustion answered, i wondered if it was possible, and i wanted a detailed answer to why it would or wouldn't work. I wanted someone i could talk to and would answer me with helpful, information. I end out being unsatisfied and rather annoyed at how aggressive one of the people was to me.

Must say, i came to the wrong place for this question. Just a bunch of people who are way to quick to judge.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1YNyQqbiF0 ?

Comment: In the end it all comes down to economics.

Comment: @sweber: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xR8p-w6ca8g

Comment: @sweber Yes, that's what i was looking for.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You were rather unhelpful and aggressive. I'm afraid i can't say thanks for that. Also, i was building up to it and sorry if your time is so needed, if you really thought it was time-wasting then why did you read it though? EDIT: I thought this whole stack exchange organization was for people to ask questions and have helpful feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That's not 3D.**
It's just 6 projections of a 3D object.

In order to make it 3D, you need all the projections.

In other words:
The measurement system (you) has a very high resolution in terms of the angle you can look at it. I'd go as far and say that you could look at this from any angle possible. The system to be measure on the contrary has a poor resolution in this regard. It can show only 6 different angles.

Answer (score 3):

Even a brief search would have shown you that people have done this before.

You seem to want a higher density of LEDs than is usually done.  Other than, or course, cost, this has obvious problems:

Getting rid of the heat.

Outer LEDs obscuring the inner LEDs.